# MLE question when lnx is undefined?

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

I"m having some trouble with a question from my statistics class. We have to find the MLE of $\theta$ where $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid random variables from the density

$f(x|\theta)=\theta(\theta+1)x^{\theta-1}(1-x)$

with $0\le x\le 1$ and $\theta>0$.

I've tried taking the log-likelihood, and after deriving I get

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} L(\theta|X_1,...,X_n)=\frac{n}{\theta}+\frac{n}{\theta+1}+\sum_{i=1}^n \log(x_i)=0$

which is a bit hard to isolate $\theta$. But also, isn't $\log(x_i)$ potentially undefined for $x_i=0$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: First of all your equation is at most a quadratic equation in $\theta$, so should not be too hard. Also for a continuous random variable you have a zero probability to obtain the value $0$ (and for any other values too). You have a positive probability of obtaining values in the neighborhood of $0$, but not exactly $0$.

Comment: Beta distribution, see Wikipedia article for some context.